# Node JS throwing undefined:1 [object Object]

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to create a discord bot and keep getting this error. I'm a newbie so following the tutorials online to make it work. Can you please explain why am I getting this error.

Here is the code where i'm getting the error.

```
    undefined:1
    [object Object]
```

```
request("https://link-to-a-private-json", (e, r, body) => {
    
    status = JSON.parse(body);
    games = status["content"]["content"];

    cIndex = -1;
    for(i = 0; i < games.length; i++) {
        if(games[i].name === "Game 2") {
            cIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }
```

here is a sample json

```
{
  "content": {
    "status": true,
    "content": [
      {
        "name": "Game 1",
        "status": "1",
        "icon": "https://example.com/53MGdfgdfgedNjp.bmp"
      },
      {
        "name": "Game 2",
        "status": "1",
        "icon": "https://example.com/53MGdfgfdedNjp.bmp"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: What environment is this executed in? Normally you should get sensible errors and not `undefined:1 [object Object]` - that almost sounds like some ancient browser like IE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change your variable `status` to `let status` or change it's name. The variable `status` is a reserved keyword, so you need to define it with `var`, `let` or `const` inside your scope.

```js
let body = `{"content": {"status": true, "content": [{"name": "Game 1", "status": "1", "icon": "https://example.com/53MGdfgdfgedNjp.bmp"}, {"name": "Game 2", "status": "1", "icon": "https://example.com/53MGdfgfdedNjp.bmp"}]}}`; 

// defining variable status with let
let status = JSON.parse(body);
games = status["content"]["content"];

cIndex = -1;
for(i = 0; i < games.length; i++) {
  if(games[i].name === "Game 2") {
    cIndex = i;
    break;
  }
}

console.log(cIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve with your current code is to access a nested array.
But this is an object and you will need to use a different method.

Working demo: https://replit.com/@kallefrombosnia/object-access#index.js

```
const json = `{
  "content": {
    "status": true,
    "content": [
      {
        "name": "Game 1",
        "status": "1",
        "icon": "https://example.com/53MGdfgdfgedNjp.bmp"
      },
      {
        "name": "Game 2",
        "status": "1",
        "icon": "https://example.com/53MGdfgfdedNjp.bmp"
      }
    ]
  }
}`;


// Parse json string to object
const {content} = JSON.parse(json);

// Custom found index
let cIndex = -1;

// Loop trough content array
content.content.forEach((item, index) =>{

  // Check do we have string named 'Game 2'
  if(item.name === 'Game 2'){

    // Set index
    cIndex = index;

    // Break loop
    return;
  }
  
});
```